# Laravel 5.3 Validation Regex check for True or False fails

Tags: regex, laravel, validation, laravel-5.3, laravel-validation

In Laravel 5.1, I used to do a validation check to see if a posted value is set as `true` or `false` using Regex Match. The posted value is something like this:

```
acceptTerms   true
```

I then check the value from Laravel validation like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($postData, [
  'acceptTerms'   => ["regex:(true|false)"],
]);
```

Since updating to Laravel 5.3, the above validation rules fails and always throws the error: `acceptTerms format is invalid.`.

Why is it failing and how do I check if a value is set as `true` or `false` in Laravel 5.3?

**EDIT 1:**

I forgot to add, the data posted is sent as `JSON.stringify(data)` and in Laravel I receive it as `Input::json('data')`. Would that change anything?

**EDIT 2:**

`dd($postData)` returns this:

```
array:31 [
  "id" => "8"
  "appId" => "1"
  "name" => "Asdsad"
  "acceptTerms" => true
  ]
```

Comment: ternary operator?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand.

Comment: Another point I did not add in my question yet is, the data posted is sent as `JSON.stringify(data)` and in Laravel I receive it as `Input::json('data')`. Would that change anything?

Comment: it might be helpful to post the content beeing passed to your validator making it fail. maybe simple `dd($postData)`

Comment: Thank you @nozzleman I have updated my question with the response for `dd($postData)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's boolean, you can use [`boolean`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-boolean).

I guess it's more readable than `regex`.

> The field under validation must be able to be cast as a boolean. Accepted input are true, false, 1, 0, "1", and "0".

Comment: thats it! You saved me twice today. Thank you heaps! I always thought the `boolean` check was for 1 and 0 only and never tried that in 5.3. Updating the validation to `boolean` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with [`in()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-in) as:

```
'acceptTerms'   => 'in:true,false',
```

Comment: For that I get the error `Method [validateTrue,false] does not exist.`

Comment: When using the regex pattern, it may be necessary to specify rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters, especially if the regular expression contains a pipe character.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Amit. The validation still fails and I get the `input is invalid error`. Another point I did not add in my question before was, the data posted is sent as `JSON.stringify(data)` and in Laravel I receive it as `Input::json('data')`. Would that change anything?

Comment: Can you `dd($postData)` and post in your question?

Comment: `boolean` validation works for me in this case. Thanks you for your support @Amit. I appreciate that.